Issue with Missing Product Details (Title, Quantity, Image) When Pushing to Amazon via REST API
Title:
Issue with Missing Product Details (Title, Quantity, Image) When Pushing to Amazon via REST API
Question:
I'm using the Amazon SP-API to list products on my Amazon seller account. The product appears successfully on the Amazon dashboard, but I'm encountering an issue where the product title, quantity, and image are missing. Additionally, the product status shows as "Incomplete."
Here's the process I followed:
Auth API: Successfully authenticated and obtained an access token.
Product Type Definition API: Retrieved the schema for the product type.
Listings API: Used the retrieved schema to create a new product listing.
My Payload:
{
  "productType": "APPAREL",
  "requirements": "LISTING",
  "attributes": {
    "brand": [
      {
        "value": "GENERIC",
        "language_tag": "en_US",
        "marketplace_id": "A17E79C6D8DWNP"
      }
    ],
    "bullet_point": [
      {
        "value": "it's an awesome luggage",
        "language_tag": "en_US",
        "marketplace_id": "A17E79C6D8DWNP"
      }
    ],
    "country_of_origin": [
      {
        "value": "US",
        "language_tag": "en_US",
        "marketplace_id": "A17E79C6D8DWNP"
      }
    ],
    "item_name": [
      {
        "value": "Awesome Luggage",
        "language_tag": "en_US",
        "marketplace_id": "A17E79C6D8DWNP"
      }
    ],
    "product_description": [
      {
        "value": "This is a test description",
        "language_tag": "en_US",
        "marketplace_id": "A17E79C6D8DWNP"
      }
    ],
    "supplier_declared_dg_hz_regulation": [
      {
        "value": "not_applicable",
        "language_tag": "en_US",
        "marketplace_id": "A17E79C6D8DWNP"
      }
    ],
    "recommended_browse_nodes": [
      {
        "value": "12587455",
        "marketplace_id": "A17E79C6D8DWNP"
      }
    ],
    "merchant_suggested_asin": [
      {
        "value": "B007KQBXN0",
        "marketplace_id": "A17E79C6D8DWNP"
      }
    ],
    "item_package_dimensions": [
      {
        "height": {
          "value": 2.7,
          "unit": "inches"
        },
        "length": {
          "value": 10,
          "unit": "inches"
        },
        "width": {
          "value": 2,
          "unit": "inches"
        },
        "marketplace_id": "A17E79C6D8DWNP"
      }
    ],
    "batteries_required": [
      {
        "value": true,
        "marketplace_id": "A17E79C6D8DWNP"
      }
    ],
    "color": [
      {
        "value": "Cranberry",
        "standardized_values": ["Red"],
        "language_tag": "en_US",
        "marketplace_id": "A17E79C6D8DWNP"
      }
    ],
    "externally_assigned_product_identifier": [
      {
        "title": "Item Package Dimensions",
        "description": "Provide the item's package dimensions"
      }
    ],
    "manufacturer": [
      {
        "value": "Everyday Manufacturing Company",
        "language_tag": "en_US",
        "marketplace_id": "A17E79C6D8DWNP"
      }
    ],
    "unit_count": [
      {
        "value": 72.0,
        "type": {
          "value": "Ounces",
          "language_tag": "en_US"
        },
        "marketplace_id": "A17E79C6D8DWNP"
      }
    ],
    "item_package_weight": [
      {
        "value": 0.65,
        "unit": "pounds",
        "marketplace_id": "A17E79C6D8DWNP"
      }
    ],
    "batteries_included": [
      {
        "value": true,
        "marketplace_id": "A17E79C6D8DWNP"
      }
    ],
    "battery": [
      {
        "cell_composition": [
          {
            "value": "alkaline"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "list_price": [
      {
        "currency": "SAR",
        "value_with_tax": 69,
        "marketplace_id": "A17E79C6D8DWNP"
      }
    ],
    "target_gender": [
      {
        "value": "female",
        "marketplace_id": "A17E79C6D8DWNP"
      }
    ],
    "department": [
      {
        "value": "Unisex Baby",
        "language_tag": "en_US",
        "marketplace_id": "A17E79C6D8DWNP"
      }
    ],
    "outer": [
      {
        "material": [
          {
            "value": "Leather",
            "language_tag": "en_US"
          },
          {
            "value": "Carbon Fiber",
            "language_tag": "en_US"
          }
        ],
        "marketplace_id": "A17E79C6D8DWNP"
      }
    ],
    "age_range_description": [
      {
        "value": "Toddler",
        "language_tag": "en_US",
        "marketplace_id": "A17E79C6D8DWNP"
      }
    ],
    "weave_type": [
      {
        "value": "Jacquard",
        "language_tag": "en_US",
        "marketplace_id": "A17E79C6D8DWNP"
      }
    ],
    "model_name": [
      {
        "value": "MacBook Pro",
        "language_tag": "en_US",
        "marketplace_id": "A17E79C6D8DWNP"
      }
    ],
    "care_instructions": [
      {
        "value": "Hand Wash Only",
        "language_tag": "en_US",
        "marketplace_id": "A17E79C6D8DWNP"
      }
    ],
    "fabric_type": [
      {
        "value": "75% Cotton, 15% Nylon, 10% Rayon",
        "language_tag": "en_US",
        "marketplace_id": "A17E79C6D8DWNP"
      }
    ],
    "size": [
      {
        "value": "X-Large",
        "language_tag": "en_US",
        "marketplace_id": "A17E79C6D8DWNP"
      }
    ],
    "closure": [
      {
        "type": [
          {
            "value": "Zipper",
            "language_tag": "en_US"
          }
        ],
        "marketplace_id": "A17E79C6D8DWNP"
      }
    ],
    "condition_type": [
      {
        "value": "new_new",
        "marketplace_id": "A17E79C6D8DWNP"
      }
    ],
    "style": [
      {
        "value": "Art Deco",
        "language_tag": "en_US",
        "marketplace_id": "A17E79C6D8DWNP"
      }
    ],
    "main_product_image_locator": [
      {
        "marketplace_id": "A17E79C6D8DWNP",
        "media_location": "https://d1gpzof0viq1mp.cloudfront.net/products/thumb/073120200027085f23655c3b789.png"
      }
    ],
    "item_name": [
      {
        "language_tag": "en_US",
        "marketplace_id": "A17E79C6D8DWNP",
        "value": "Adidas Blue Sneakers"
      }
    ],
    "list_price": [
      {
        "currency": "SAR",
        "value_with_tax": 1.00,
        "marketplace_id": "A17E79C6D8DWNP"
      }
    ]
  }
}

My Response:
{
  "sku": "3333-4567-8910",
  "status": "ACCEPTED",
  "submissionId": "bf09b1753c174a1cbba81b63568560e1",
  "issues": []
}

Problem:
Despite providing these details, the product's title, quantity, and image are missing on the Amazon dashboard, and the status is marked as "Incomplete."
Troubleshooting Steps Taken:

Changed the product type and verified the schema for relevant fields.
Checked for any issues or errors in the response.

Questions:

What could be causing the product details (title, quantity, image) to be missing?
Are there specific required fields for the product to be considered complete on Amazon?
How can I ensure that all product details are correctly submitted and displayed?


Did you manage to work out what was wrong?


What could be causing the product details (title, quantity, image) to be missing?

As far as I know, images must be uploaded to Amazon S3.

Are there specific required fields for the product to be considered complete on Amazon?

Normally the offer stays in an Incomplete state if it is missing image, quantity and/or price. In your case probably is a combination of these elements, probably the image.

How can I ensure that all product details are correctly submitted and displayed?

Before calling putListingsItem, validate your JSON message agains the JSON schema. If it is valid, as yours is, when sending it you will 99.99% get back an OK response (like the one you got). But this is not enough, you will have to check if there were asynchronous validation errors raised by Amazon.
In order to get them, call the getListingsItem passing issues in the includedData parameter. In the response you can then check if there are pending issues.
